# check if the series converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Check if the following series is convergent or divergent: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{4k^2+1}}$$
By the comparison test the series schould be divergent. I need a divergent series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k$ such that $0\le b_k \le \frac{2}{\sqrt{4k^2+1}}$ for all sufficient large natural k. But I don't know what $b_k$ could be, with $b_k=\frac{1}{k}$ I don't get $0\le b_k \le \frac{2}{\sqrt{4k^2+1}}$ for all sufficient large natural k. Could you help me?

Comment: Try $b_k=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{(2k+1)^2}}$, for all $k\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Note that $\frac{2}{\sqrt{4k^2+1}}\gt \frac{2}{\sqrt{4k^2+12k^2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

In short: it diverges because you can compare it with Harmonic series

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{4k^2+1}}\geq \frac{2}{2k+1}$$